# how to implement a paypal config file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, configuration-files

i'm trying to separate paypal config info from application/paypal_library file. Basically the config info are API_username, API_pwd, API_signiture etc.

The original structure is like this:

```
class Paypal_library {

    protected $ci;

    public $API_UserName = xxx;
    public $API_Password = xxx;
    public $API_Signature = xxx;
    ...
    ...
    function __construct() {
        $this->ci = & get_instance();
    }
    otherfunctions
```

so I move these variables in a new  config file called config/paypal_config.php. 
and put

```
$config['paypal_api_username'] =xxx;
$config['paypal_api_password'] = xxx;
$config['paypal_api_signature'] = xxx;
```

But i got a problem when i call this config file in paypal_library.php.
I used:

```
    protected $ci;

    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("paypal_config",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('paypal_config');

    public $API_UserName = $config['paypal_api_username'];
    public $API_Password = $config['paypal_api_password'];
    public $API_Signature = $config['paypal_api_signature'];
    ...
    ...
    function __construct() {
        $this->ci = & get_instance();
    }
```

But this doesn't work, because it seems that i cannot put $CI=&get_instance() before constructor? However, if i put them inside constructor, paypal can't find those variables during payment process.

so how can i implement paypal_config file here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the properties in the constructor.

```
function __construct()
{
  $this->ci =& get_instance();
  $this->ci->load->config('paypal_config', TRUE);
  $config = $this->ci->config->item('paypal_config');

  $this->API_UserName = $config['paypal_api_username'];
  $this->API_Password = $config['paypal_api_password'];
  $this->API_Signature = $config['paypal_api_signature'];
}
```

A class can only contain [method and property definitions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

The operations in your example before the API property definitions are syntactically incorrect and will cause a parse error.

Comment: but as paypal processing the payment, it throws error like "variable undefined". so it seems that those variables have to be outside construct to let paypal access?

Comment: What is the exact error?  Are you processing the paypal payment in the library or in a controller?

Comment: hi, problem solved by using your method! no error shows. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's ilogic to initialize the instance outside any method. You should initialize it in the construt method for it to be available during the class execution.

Regarding the fact that you can't access those variables, I've seen you've put the variables in a public state. Why don't you make them private so other classes won't access them (for security reasons) and build some get Methods to get their state?

```
private $API_UserName = $config['paypal_api_username'];
public get_PaypalUsername(){

     return $this->CI->API_UserName;

}
```

EDIT:

Forgot to say that the variables should be intialized within the _construct method as well allways binding to your Singleton instance

```
public __construct()
{
   $this->ci = & get_instance();
   $this->CI->API_UserName = $API_UserName;
   //etc

}
```